# Getting data members through void function (c++)

Tags: c++

Let's say I have private data members int x and  int y in a class. I know I can get the data members respectively, for example, through:

```
int getX() { return x; } 
int getY() { return y; }
```

There seems to be another function which can do the similar jobs:

```
void getXY(int &aX, int &aY) const {aX = x; aY = y;}
```

How can I use this function to do something the same as  the above---to obtain x and y respectively?

Comment: You already wrote the function which does that, so what's the question here? How to call a function in C++?

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo {
    int x = 2, y = 3;
public:
    void xy(int &x, int &y) const {
        x = this->x;
        y = this->y;
    }
};

int main() {
    int x, y;
    foo{}.xy(x, y);

    cout << x << " " << y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do it by simply calling the function.

```
int a = getX();
int b = getY();
```

Is similar to

```
int a,b;
getXY(a,b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a single value getter function is simple and efficient:

```
void needs_x_only( Foo const& object )
{
    int const x = object.x();   // Using single item getter function.
    (void) x;
}
```

If the `x()` function is `inline` the compiler will most probably optimize this down to a direct access of the relevant data member.

Using a multi-item getter designed as a routine with out-arguments, can be less clear if you don't need all the items, and it prevents use of `const` for the arguments. One way to support `const` (which is generally desirable) is to write a little wrapper function. E.g.,

```
auto position_of( Foo const& object )
    -> Point<int>
{
    int x;
    int y;
    object.get_xy( x, y );      // Using out-arguments getter routine.
    return {x, y};
}
```

Here `Point` is some class that defines a 2D point `struct`.

Then use of the wrapper can look like this:

```
void needs_both_x_and_y( Foo const& object )
{
    Point<int> const position = position_of( object );
    (void) position;
}
```